# Is there a way to export/import the System Settings?

Tags: 11.10

I've just installed 11.10 on a Samsung N130 netbook. I've tweaked it a little to accommodate the low hardware power.

Almost all the config was done through the default "System Settings" menu, and I've also tweaked some "advanced" features through `gnome-tweak-tools`.

I know that I'll have to install 11.10 on machines with almost identical hardware in the coming weeks. I would really like avoiding manually changing config options in the GUI every time.

Is there an easy way to export all those config changes so I can easily import them in a brand new 11.10 install later ?

Answer (score 1):

So far I've found that directories `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/` and `~/.gconf/apps/metacity/` holds most of the config file of what I tweaked.

I guess there's no simple way to make a complete export of one's config, but instead a lot of config files for each app edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could install dconf-tools and write a script that uses dconf-editor to set the tools. Then those settings could be applied anywhere. However, I don't know of a tool that automatically exports your current dconf like this.